# Style issue when overriding getDropDownView in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, view, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I'm experiencing a strange behavior when overriding **getDropDownView** method of `ArrayAdapter`. I need to override this method in order to show correct string value out from my custom object. Thats how my array adapter look like:

```
ArrayAdapter<NoteType> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NoteType>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstNoteTypes){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView lbl = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        lbl.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return lbl;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView lbl = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        lbl.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return lbl;
    }
};
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

So when I override `getDropDownView`, my Spinner looks as below - the item height is very small in size and which is not what I want:

[image]

But when I comment (or don't override) the `getDropDownView` method then it looks fine with the default styling but then I can't inject the required text value into drop down items.
[image]

Note the height of items in both images just because of overriding `getDropDownView`.

Any suggestions? or what am I missing in my code?

Comment: Not yet. So temporarily i end up over-riding `toString()` method. Are you using **ActionbarSherlock** in your project?

Comment: Yes but I don't see what difference it makes. In my case I just solved  it by creating a custom adapter instantiating a custom view with padding.

Comment: I think somehow ABS is causing the issue. I didn't want to add more files for getting a simple thing get done, so I went with `toString` shortcut. Anyhow, now I've ditched ABS in my project and will try again to see if the problem is due to this library.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote NoteType yourself, override toString() in it. Just add the following to your NoteType-class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();
}
```

Comment: I know I can escape this fuzz by simply overriding `toString()` method and for which it works fine, but unfortunately that's not my requirement. I need to override `getDropDownView` method and later extend it with some extra feature.

Answer (score 2):

I think I *might* know why this happens, but I have to test it, so for now here is another (quick) solution.

Since the `Spinner` calls `toString()` on every object in the `ArrayAdapter`, you could override the `toString()` method in your `NoteType` class and let it return your String (instead of the default `toString()` implementation). This way you wouldn't have to override `getDropDownView()`  in your adapter, but still have the default styling and your data in it.

Comment: I know I can escape this fuzz by simply overriding `toString()` method and for which it works fine, but unfortunately that's not my requirement. I need to override `getDropDownView` method and later extend it with some extra feature

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem with a custom BaseAdapter class. This was also mentioned in a comment, but the solution is actually really simple -- just add padding to the TextView you return from the getDropDownView method.

You shouldn't need to add any extra files for this and I was not using ActionBarSherlock (just the default Spinner), so I don't think it's related to that. Here is the code that worked for me, adapted to your example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Create custom TextView
    TextView lbl = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    lbl.setText(getItem(position).getName());

    // Add padding to the TextView, scaled to device
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int px = (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f);
    lbl.setPadding(px, px, px, px);

    return lbl;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Create custom TextView
    TextView lbl = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    lbl.setText(getItem(position).getName());

    // Add padding to the TextView, scaled to device
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int px = (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f);
    lbl.setPadding(px, px, px, px);

    return lbl
}
```

Comment: Of course, it will be fine with padding but the problem is why does it change its behavior when override? For the moment I've solved this by overriding **toString** in my object's custom class.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I think the key is to use this constructor: ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) and pass the resource id of the TextView within your spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Had to do the same thing so  made my own view to be used as checkedTextView

in this  the most important thing is setting the height like so 
**android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"**
**I was using a base adapter**